# Difference between java doc and Android doc in method documents

Tags: java, android, javadoc

Some times I see problematic differences between Java doc and Android doc in about method documents.For example in about `setReadable (boolean readable, boolean ownerOnly)` method you can see [java doc](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Fio%2FFile.html&ei=HVRtVZXiMMajU_O9g9AI&usg=AFQjCNEjyeMmmEUkpueuuuhfNhxO_NQURg&sig2=ElwKuzcAHer0Hmq4YMACnw&bvm=bv.94911696,d.d24) says that:

> Throws: SecurityException - If a security manager exists and its
>   SecurityManager.checkWrite(java.lang.String) method denies write
>   access to the file

But [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setReadable(boolean,%20boolean)) does not say any thing about throwing exception.Also we know that [Docs say](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fessential%2Fexceptions%2Fruntime.html&ei=nVNtVfveO8G2UpbugOAI&usg=AFQjCNEGw5ttyuCKkafMevAmbZP4PKzSdQ&sig2=EpeAx9ZJKK5p2wg52iCJJQ&bvm=bv.94911696,d.d24):

> Any Exception that can be thrown by a method is part of the method's
>   public programming interface. Those who call a method must know about
>   the exceptions that a method can throw so that they can decide what to
>   do about them.

So when we do not see any throw condition in Android documents of a method,

1. Does it mean method will not throw exception any way?Or it may be forgotten?
2. Do we need to check documents for any simple method for probability difference between Java and Android?Is it possible?

Comment: Android does not claim Java 1.6 portability

Comment: @Alex Java uses `setReadable` method since version 1.6.Also Android use a class with the same name in the same package,so why those differes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the declaration of setReadable(bool,bool) you'll see that the exception is caught and false is returned instead. So in this case the Android documentation supersedes the Javadoc.

Comment: you can see details in `return` part of method in both Java and Android are similar.

Comment: I'm not talking about the doc. I'm talking about the source. The android implementation of setReadable catches any exception and returns false instead. That's why the Android doc doesn't mention any exception.

Answer (score 0):

As you may already know,exceptions may occur in your code at run time, due to the closure of the code. Simply put, you may be using a method safely and correctly, but that specific block of code that's surrounding it, may be vulnerable to some exceptions and conditions. Also android docs may suffer from poor references for native java libraries and apis.Because they assume that you are an experienced java developer and are familiar with using javadocs.

Comment: I'm suspicious in about your idea.They could simply use java docs in their documentation.

Comment: As with your experience, they haven't done that for some methods !